# Hemispheres with some property

Tags: mapping

You surely know the ["water hemisphere"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_and_water_hemispheres) of Earth. Have other hemispheres been computed? (For example, Wiki notes "population hemisphere" coincides more or less with the "land hemisphere", which is not surprising.) "Temperature hemisphere" might be interesting, but perhaps too variable.

Comment: Using the word **surely** in this situation is somewhat presumptuous. You may know of it, but others may not.